# Failed to write to Database via ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have built a facebook app by which people have logged in to the app and took part in a small competition. I built it using facebook php SDK along with jQuery and javascript. The thing is that after the app was ready the client stated that three participants took part and are not found in the database.

The structure of the write to database happens upon a click of a 'submit' button which through jQuery, calls a php file to do the rest. Is it possible that form the user side the jQuery function is never executed? because the client demands an answer why specific participants are not found in the database. Yet the app functioned perfectly normal with other users.

My question is this, is it possible for jQuery to fail an ajax call to fail for specific browsers?

Comment: There is not enough to go on. It is unlikely that jQuery itself fails - although there are *many* reasons why the application is failing in the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

It does not depend on the browser. The only thing necessary for the browser is to have Javascript enabled, so make sure that's the case.

You can use the error method provided when using an AJAX call to see if the call successfully returns data. If not, your server-side code is either getting no data or runs into runtime errors.

I suggest you start debugging your application using the console from the moment the 'submit' button was clicked. This can also answer your question of the function never to be executed. So for the Javascript, use client-side debugging.

If you're still having trouble, please provide code samples or a jsfiddle.